# Using fund() in r to find frequency

Tags: r, frequency, trigonometry

I'm trying to analyse a sine wave and print out it's frequency along with the specific times. Unfortunately Im getting the error

```
In fund(samples, f = sampleRate, wl = timeSize, ovlp = 0, fmax = maxFreq,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Here is the code

```
library(tuneR) 
library(seewave)

printFrequencyAndTime <- function(filename) {
    waveform <- readWave(filename) 
    sampleRate <- waveform@samp.rate #44100
    samples <- waveform@left #array vector
nOfSamples <- length(samples) #132301
    maxFreq <- sampleRate/2
    minFreq <- 0
    timeSize <- 512 
    pi <- 3.1415926535
    nOfFreqBands <- 512 # number of frequency bands
    freqAverage <- 64 #group n number of frequency bands together 

    #fundamental frequency track
    ff <- fund(samples, f= sampleRate, wl = timeSize, ovlp = 0, fmax = maxFreq, threshold = NULL, from = 0, to = 3, plot = TRUE, xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Frequency (kHz)", ylim = c(0, sampleRate/2000), pb = FALSE)
    #bandNumber[j] <- j*sampleRate/timeSize

  cat("Frequency is ",ff, "Hz; time is ", t, "s.") 
}
```

Its been bugging me for a while now so can anyone tell me if my approach is correcting. I'm thinking I need to do the fourier transform of my sine wave data into the freq components, then i need to get the frequency with the maximum amplitude and that will be the frequency of my sine wave.

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible "filename" data file to test. It's quite possible some data are not of the class you think they are, so they can't be coerced to numeric values.  If you run the examples (`fund(sheep,...)` ) what happens?

Comment: The data file is WAV and I've looked at the 'samples' in R and its just an array of values.